# Spilt water on Macbook keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Yesterday I spilt a lot of water on my Macbook pro keyboard.
The laptop seems to work fine but a few keys don't work well.
Left control and left shift don't work,
Left alt and right alt are not tested.

1. How can I test if left and right Alt key work well?
2. This macbook pro is late 2011 version. I don't have Apple care.
   What is the most recommended action I can take in this situation?

PS. Right after the spilt, I pushed a lot of keys to wipe out water with paper towel,
then flipped it upside down. (I didn't turn it off)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you want to hope that was *clean* water, no sugars, no coffee or tea or juice etc!

It's a large area to dry properly but even though you might think it's dry, it's probably not yet, you may want to consider trying the following:

- Place the laptop near a dehumidifier (preferably near the intake) to try to draw out water for several hours
- Place the laptop in a highly air conditioned room, aircon removes moisture from the air, you may need to place a fan blowing air over the unit to encourage the water to become airborn
- Place the unit in a sealed bin bag with a lot of salt or dry rice in it (be *really* careful not to get this on or in your unit, salt water will corrode your laptop like thing else, put the laptop on a cardboard shelf over the salt/rice)
- If you have a load of silica gel bags (they come with loads of things, I got a particularly big one with an iMac once leave them on the keyboard and seal it in a bag to try to draw moisture out.  (Top Tip, keep a bag with silica gel bags in it, whenever you get one in something, save it!)

All of the above may take several attempts to work, or may simply not work.

Finally, you can disassemble the keyboard unit, this may be to try to dry it further, or to replace if it turns out to be broken, it's not too difficult a job, lookup your model on [iFixIT](http://www.ifixit.com).

Comment: Fortunately, it was clean water. 

By the way, I can't find 'keyboard' on iFixIT. Is it included in 'Upper case'?

Comment: It depends on your exact model, but the steps should be similar for any similar model, this is an example http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Core+Duo+Model+A1150+Keyboard+Replacement/484#s2261, or look for a "teardown" guide which strips the whole machine, and see how they get the keyboard out.  Drop your model number in a coment if you cannot find anything

Comment: My model is A1276 (MacBook Pro Late 2011, 15"). It seems to be 'Unibody' model